# Extending ggplot geom_polygon to end of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make a confidence interval band that extends to the end of the plot in ggplot?

I can do it if the plotted band is entirely within the plot, for example

```
limits <- c(1e2, 1e7)
confPolygon <- tibble(
    x = c(limits[1], limits[1]*10, limits[2], limits[2], limits[2]/10, limits[1], limits[1]), 
    y = c(limits[1], limits[1], limits[2]/10, limits[2], limits[2], limits[1]*10, limits[1])
)
plot <- ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = confPolygon, aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "grey", alpha = .25) +
    scale_x_log10(limits = limits) + 
    scale_y_log10(limits = limits)
```

works. However, if I try any shape that extends the polygon to the edges

```
confPolygon <- tibble(
    x = c(limits[1], limits[2]*10, limits[2]*10, limits[1], limits[1]), 
    y = c(limits[1], limits[1], limits[2]*10, limits[2]*10, limits[1])
)
```

then it doesn't plot the polygon.

Comment: can't test at the moment, but adding `oob=scales::squish` inside your `scale_*_log10` specifications might do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the method you are using to zoom in to the plot (setting limits within the x or y scales) isn't meant to zoom in; it actually subsets the data, accidentally creating missing values on the way. Use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5))`, or in your case, `coord_cartesian(xlim = limits, ylim = limits)` instead, as this step does not subset the data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with `oob=scales::squish()`.

```
plot2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = confPolygon, aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "grey", alpha = .25) +
  scale_x_log10(limits = limits, oob=scales::squish) + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = limits, oob=scales::squish)
```

If you really want the polygon to extend all the way to the edge, you should also add `expand=c(0,0)` to each of the `scale_*_log10()` argument lists.